# How to preserve ordering of items in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this say:

```
a = {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
```

Now when I print it prints in an very random order. Whereas I need it to preserve the order always. How can I go about doing this in python?

Comment: Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: As a much delayed follow-up, dictionaries are now order preserving in Python 3.6 as an implementation detail, and as a language feature in 3.7 and above.  [A great write-up is found in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/211827)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use OrderedDict class. Example below.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict=OrderedDict()
dict['first']=1
dict['second']=2
dict['third']=3
dict
```